# How can I move the location of my ESP to a secondary drive? (Windows 10)

Tags: linux, windows-10, raid, efi, intel-rst

Currently, I am attempting a dual boot installation of Windows + Linux, but I am encountering issues with Intel RST. Apparently, it's complex to get linux to be able to access an RST RAID configuration. I have 2 hard drives partitioned as follows

Hard Drive 1 (Intel RST w/ RAID 1) [256 Gb]

`|ESP| Windows Recovery | Windows Primary (C:)| Microsoft Reserved|`

Hard Drive 0 [1 Tb]

`| Windows Secondary (D:)| Unallocated Space |`

I plan to install Arch-linux using the Unallocated Space. Essentially, Instead of trying to access the ESP on the Hard Drive 1, I want to move it to Hard Drive 0, so I don't have to deal with RAID in Linux.

1. How can I move the ESP to Hard Drive 0?
2. Will this solve my issues?
3. Will I still be able to boot Windows on Hard Drive 1?

Thanks!
Help is Appreciated.

Comment: If you install the grub it automatically detect EFI partition and other OSes. No need to move EFI.

Answer (score 1):

- To move the ESP used by Windows, first create a new blank ESP on the new disk, then use Windows' own `bcdboot` tool to copy the necessary files to it (and to generate an NVRAM boot entry).

  While doing so, make sure to use `/s` to select the drive letter of the new ESP, if you haven't deleted the old one yet.
- If you plan on using the firmware boot menu to select the OS, you can create a new ESP on disk 0 without doing anything to the existing ESP on disk 1.

  Each disk can have its own EFI system partition. EFI NVRAM boot entries don't just look for "a" system partition, they also record its UUID – so different entries can point to different system partitions.